# SSRS configuration issues

Tags: reporting-services, configuration

I need to configure SSRS 2014 on my private laptop.
After using "SQL SERVER 2014 REPORTING SERVICES CONFIGURATION MANAGER" I am trying to enter the URL. I am getting in "REPORT MANAGER URL" but the website is  asking for username and password. I am using windows authentication on my SQL SERVER so I don't know why SSRS needs username and password.
Is my configuration wrong?
[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this and enter ssrs on my laptop?

Comment: What edition of windows?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS uses Windows Athentication to determine access to certain folders. Try executing Internet Explorer as administrator to access http://127.0.0.1:80/Reports and grant access to your user (Top Right-> Configuration-> Security)

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? Are you using Chrome or Internet Explorer?

I have found that when you initially connect via Chrome to the SSRS reporting page it will ask you to authenticate once. With Internet Explorer windows authentication should be set by default:
https://www.specopssoft.com/configuring-chrome-and-firefox-for-windows-integrated-authentication/

As vercilli also pointed out, you will need to set system level and item level privileges to view/edit/publish reports and administer the server from the web front-end.